# Does C++ have "with" keyword like Pascal?

Tags: c++, pascal, with-statement

`with` keyword in Pascal can be use to quick access the field of a record. 
Anybody knows if C++ has anything similar to that?

Ex:
I have a pointer with many fields and i don't want to type like this:

```
if (pointer->field1) && (pointer->field2) && ... (pointer->fieldn)
```

what I really want is something like this in C++:

```
with (pointer)
{
  if (field1) && (field2) && .......(fieldn)
}
```

Comment: Huh. Javascript has the `with` keyword and it does substantially the same thing; I didn't realize it had a pedigree reaching back to Pascal (!).

Comment: Maybe it comes from Cobol or ADA, who knows...

Comment: There is a with in Ada, but not with that meaning.

Comment: There is a with in Vb and in Vb.Net with the same meaning too.

Comment: But in VB you need to say With obj / .X = x, so it's not as ambiguous

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++, you can put code in a method of the class being reference by `pointer`. There you can directly reference the members without using the pointer. Make it `inline` and you pretty much get what you want.

Comment: What do you mean for “make it `inline`”? Can you declare the method just inside another function? It's weird...

Comment: @Dacav This answer is just suggesting to add a method to the class being used by `with`. Being `inline` allows it to go into a header but otherwise that's a red herring. Such a method must be declared in its original class, and defined outside any other function. My answer below has a workaround to both problems.

Answer (score 28):

Probably the closest you can get is this: (this is just an academic exercise. Of course, you can't use any local variables in the body of these artificial `with` blocks!)

```
struct Bar {
    int field;
};

void foo( Bar &b ) {
    struct withbar : Bar { void operator()() {
        cerr << field << endl;
    }}; static_cast<withbar&>(b)();
}
```

Or, a bit more demonically,

```
#define WITH(T) do { struct WITH : T { void operator()() {
#define ENDWITH(X) }}; static_cast<WITH&>((X))(); } while(0)

struct Bar {
    int field;
};

void foo( Bar &b ) {
    if ( 1+1 == 2 )
        WITH( Bar )
            cerr << field << endl;
        ENDWITH( b );
}
```

or in C++0x

```
#define WITH(X) do { auto P = &X; \
 struct WITH : typename decay< decltype(X) >::type { void operator()() {
#define ENDWITH }}; static_cast<WITH&>((*P))(); } while(0)

        WITH( b )
            cerr << field << endl;
        ENDWITH;
```

Comment: Very nice :). I'd like to mention though that for those few of us that work with the Metrowerks compiler, this is quite likely not to work (it doesn't deal well with structs in a function)

Comment: @arke: really? That's surprising, I loved Metrowerks when it was the Mac standard. Hmm, it looks like they lost Howard Hinnant…

Comment: you can use static variables though.

Comment: In c++17, it would be better to do `if(auto a=foo();true){/**/}`

Answer (score 22):

no there is no such keyword.

Answer (score 17):

I like to use:

```
    #define BEGIN_WITH(x) { \
        auto &_ = x;

    #define END_WITH() }
```

Example:

```
    BEGIN_WITH(MyStructABC)
    _.a = 1;
    _.b = 2;
    _.c = 3;
    END_WITH()
```

Answer (score 9):

Even though I program mostly in Delphi which has a `with` keyword (since Delphi is a Pascal derivative), I don't use `with`.  As others have said: it saves a bit on typing, but reading is made harder.

In a case like the code below it might be tempting to use `with`:

```
cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records.FieldByName('foo').Value = 1;
cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records.FieldByName('bar').Value = 2;
cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records.FieldByName('baz').Value = 3;
```

Using `with` this looks like this

```
with cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records do
begin
  FieldByName('foo').Value = 1;
  FieldByName('bar').Value = 2;
  FieldByName('baz').Value = 3;
end;
```

I prefer to use a different technique by introducing an extra variable pointing to the same thing `with` would be pointing to.  Like this:

```
var lRecords: TDataSet;

lRecords := cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records;

lRecords.FieldByName('foo').Value = 1;
lRecords.FieldByName('bar').Value = 2;
lRecords.FieldByName('baz').Value = 3;
```

This way there is no ambiguity, you save a bit on typing and the intent of the code is clearer than using `with`

Comment: This strategy works with C++ too, using a local `T&` or `T const&` variable to hold a reference to the long expression (which must be a proper lvalue in the `T&` case).  To make it visually stand out, I usually name the variable `_`.

Answer (score 6):

No, C++ does not have any such keyword.

Answer (score 6):

The closest you can get is [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining):

```
myObj->setX(x)
     ->setY(y)
     ->setZ(z)
```

for setting multiple fields and `using` for namespaces.

Comment: This is actually sick good, because encapsulation is preserved... Thanks for making the connection!

Comment: it is NOT BY FAR the same!

Answer (score 5):

C++ does not have a feature like that. And many consider "WITH" in Pascal to be a problem because it can make the code ambiguous and hard to read, for example it hard to know if field1 is a member of pointer or a local variable or something else. Pascal also allows multiple with-variables such as "With Var1,Var2" which makes it even harder.

Comment: There is always the question that if something can be abused, means that it is bad.

Comment: Sure, because name lookup in C++ is *so straightforward*. No -1, but I think the "can make code ambiguous" argument falls flat when you consider the case of argument-dependent lookup for functions, especially for instantiations of function templates.

Comment: I agree it can be useful but I've seen it abused so many times now that I stay away from using it. In particular it can bite you if field1 is renamed in the record so your with-code now suddenly silently refers to another variable in scope with the same name. Instead of with I use one of the other approaches suggested here: use a local variable with short name or move it to a function/method.

Comment: Upvote. The worst language feature. Consider this abomination: with struct1, struct2.substruct3, struct4.substruct5.ptrstruct6^... Seen it.

Comment: Visual Basic tidied up the syntax by requiring the fields belonging to the 'with' to be prefixed with a "." - it also helped syntax completion etc.  Our host Joel did that :)

Comment: Not dangerous if you apply it only on a single type (record, structure, object, etc). In other words, never mix objects inside the "with" and your safe.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
with (OBJECT) {CODE}
```

There is no such thing in C++.
You can put CODE as is into a method of OBJECT, but it is not always desirable.

With C++11 you can get quite close by creating alias with short name for OBJECT.
For example code given in question it will look like so:

```cpp
{
    auto &_ = *pointer;
    if (_.field1 && ... && _.fieldn) {...}
}
```

(The surrounding curly braces are used to limit visibility of alias `_` )

If you use some field very often you can alias it directly:

```cpp
auto &field = pointer->field;
// Even shorter alias:
auto &_ = pointer->busy_field;
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no `with` keyword in C/C++.

But you can add it with some preprocessor code:

```
/* Copyright (C) 2018 Piotr Henryk Dabrowski, Creative Commons CC-BY 3.0 */

#define __M2(zero, a1, a2, macro, ...) macro

#define __with2(object, as) \
    for (typeof(object) &as = (object), *__i = 0; __i < (void*)1; ++__i)

#define __with1(object) __with2(object, it)

#define with(...) \
    __M2(0, ##__VA_ARGS__, __with2(__VA_ARGS__), __with1(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Usage:

```
with (someVeryLongObjectNameOrGetterResultOrWhatever) {
    if (it)
        it->...
    ...
}

with (someVeryLongObjectNameOrGetterResultOrWhatever, myObject) {
    if (myObject)
        myObject->...
    ...
}
```

Simplified unoverloaded definitions (choose one):

unnamed (Kotlin style `it`):

```
#define with(object) \
    for (typeof(object) &it = (object), *__i = 0; __i < (void*)1; ++__i)
```

named:

```
#define with(object, as) \
    for (typeof(object) &as = (object), *__i = 0; __i < (void*)1; ++__i)
```

Of course the `for` loop always has only a single pass and will be optimized out by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach relies on Boost. If your compiler supports C++0x's `auto` then you can use that and get rid of the Boost dependence.

**Disclaimer**: please don't do this in any code that must be maintained or read by someone else (or even by yourself in a few months):

```
#define WITH(src_var)                                             \
    if(int cnt_ = 1)                                              \
        for(BOOST_AUTO(const & _, src_var); cnt_; --cnt_)


int main()
{
    std::string str = "foo";

    // Multiple statement block
    WITH(str)
    {
        int i = _.length();
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }

    // Single statement block
    WITH(str)
        std::cout << _ << "\n";

    // Nesting
    WITH(str)
    {
        std::string another("bar");
        WITH(another)
            assert(_ == "bar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I've heard that anybody doesn't like 'with'. The rules are perfectly straightforward, no different from what happens inside a class in C++ or Java. And don't overlook that it can trigger a significant compiler optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Having written numerous parsers, this seems like a dead simple list look up for the named object, either static or dynamic. Further, I have never seen a situation where the compiler did not correctly identify the missing object and type, so all those lame excuses for not allowing a WITH ...ENDWITH construction would seem to be a lot of hooey.  For the rest of us prone to long object names one workaround is to create simple defines.  Couldn't resist, suppose I have:

```
    #include<something> 
    typedef int headache;
    class grits{
      public:
       void corn(void);
       void cattle(void);
       void hay(void);}; //insert function defs here
     void grits::grits(void)(printf("Welcome to Farm-o-mania 2012\n");};

    #define m mylittlepiggy_from_under_the_backporch.
    headache main(){
       grits mylittlepiggy_from_under_the_backporch;
         m corn();  //works in GCC
         m cattle();
         m hay();
      return headache;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct with_iter {
  with_iter( T &val ) : p(&val) {}

  inline T* begin() { return p; }
  inline T* end() { return p+1; }

  T *p;
};

#define with( N, I ) for( auto &N : with_iter<decltype(I)>(I) )

int main() {

  with( out , cout ) {
    out << "Hello world!" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Nuf said ...

Answer (score 0):

I can see one instance where 'with' is actually useful.

In methods for recursive data structures, you often have the case:

```
void A::method()
{
  for (A* node = this; node; node = node->next) {
    abc(node->value1);
    def(value2); // -- oops should have been node->value2
    xyz(node->value3);
  }
}
```

errors caused by typos like this are very hard to find.

With 'with' you could write

```
void A::method()
{
  for (A* node = this; node; node = node->next) with (node) {
    abc(value1);
    def(value2);
    xyz(value3);
  }
}
```

This probably doesn't outweight all the other negatives mentioned for 'with', but just as an interesting info...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can:

```
auto p = *pointer;
if (p.field1) && (p.field2) && ... (p.fieldn)
```

Or create a small program that will understand `with` statements in C++ and translate them to some form of a valid C++.

Comment: Probably should be `auto &p = *pointer`, since your code takes a copy.

Answer (score 0):

I too came from the Pascal world.....    .....and I also LOVE Python's use of `with`  (basically having an automatic try/finally):

```
  with open(filename, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
      if line.startswith("something"):
        do_more()
```

That acts like a smart ptr object.  It does not go into the block if the open failed; and when leaving the block, the file if closed.

Here is a sample very close to Pascal while also supporting Python's usage (assuming you have a smart object with destructor cleanup);   You need newer C++ standard compilers for it to work.

```
    // Old way
    cxGrid_s cxGrid{};
    cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records.FieldByName.value["foo"] = 1;
    cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records.FieldByName.value["bar"] = 2;
    cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records.FieldByName.value["baz"] = 3;
```

```
    // New Way - FieldByName will now be directly accessible.
    // the `;true` is only needed if the call does not return bool or pointer type
    if (auto FieldByName = cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records.FieldByName; true)
    {
        FieldByName.fn1 = 0;
        FieldByName.fn2 = 3;
        FieldByName.value["foo"] = 1;
        FieldByName.value["bar"] = 2;
        FieldByName.value["baz"] = 3;
    }
```

And if you want even closer:

```
    #define with if

    with (auto FieldByName = cxGrid.DBTableView.ViewData.Records.FieldByName; true)
```

```
    // Similar to the Python example
    with (smartFile sf("c:\\file.txt"); sf)
    {
        fwrite("...", 1, 3, *sf);
    }
```

```
    // Usage with a smart pointer
    with (std::unique_ptr<class_name> p = std::make_unique<class_name>())
    {
        p->DoSomethingAmazing();

        // p will be released and cleaned up upon exiting the scope
    }
```

The (quick and dirty) supporting code for this example:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
struct cxGrid_s {
    int g1, g2;
    struct DBTableView_s {
        int tv1, tv2;
        struct ViewData_s {
            int vd1, vd2;
            struct Records_s {
                int r1, r2;
                struct FieldByName_s{
                    int fn1, fn2;
                    std::map<std::string, int> value;
                } FieldByName;
            } Records;
        } ViewData;
    } DBTableView;
};

class smartFile
{
public:
    FILE* f{nullptr};
    smartFile() = delete;
    smartFile(std::string fn) { f = fopen(fn.c_str(), "w");    }
    ~smartFile()              { if (f) fclose(f); f = nullptr; }
    FILE* operator*()         { return f;            }
    FILE& operator->()        { return *f;           }
    operator bool() const     { return f != nullptr; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was lamenting to PotatoSwatter (currently accepted answer) that I could not access variables declared in the enclosing scope with that solution.
I tried to post this in a comment response to PotatoSwatter, but it's better as a whole post. It's all a bit over the top, but the syntax sugar is pretty nice!

```
#define WITH_SIG float x, float y, float z
#define WITH_ARG x, y, z

#define WITH(T,s) do { struct WITH : T { void operator()(s) {
#define ENDWITH(X,s) }}; static_cast<WITH&>((X))(s); } while(0)

class MyClass {
    Vector memberVector;
    static void myFunction(MyClass* self, WITH_SIG) {
        WITH(MyClass, WITH_SIG)
            memberVector = Vector(x,y,z);
        ENDWITH(*self, WITH_ARG);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

A simple way to do this is as follows

```
class MyClass
{
    int& m_x;

    public MyClass(int& x)
    {
        m_x = x;
        m_x++;
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        m_x--;
    }
}
int main():
{
    x = 0;
    {
        MyClass(x)  // x == 1 whilst in this scope
    }
}
```

I've been writing python all day long and just scrapped this down before anyone takes me to the cleaners. In a larger program this is an example of how to keep a reliable count for something.

Comment: This answer does not seem related to the question?