# What is the underscore before the parentheses do in C++?

Tags: c++17

I am reading the following C++17 code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

enum class Relationship { parent, child, sibling };
struct Person { string name; };
struct Relationships
{
    vector<tuple<Person, Relationship, Person>> relations;
    void add_parent_and_child(const Person& parent, const Person& child)
    {
        relations.push_back({parent, Relationship::parent, child});
        relations.push_back({child, Relationship::child, parent});
    }
};

struct Research
{
    Research (Relationships& relationships)
    {
        auto& relations = relationships.relations;
        for(auto&& [first, rel, second] : relations)
        {
            if(first.name == "John" && rel == Relationship::parent)
            {
                cout << "John has a child called "  << second.name << endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person parent {"John"};
    Person child1 {"Chris"}, child2 {"Matt"};
    Relationships relationships;
    relationships.add_parent_and_child(parent, child1);
    relationships.add_parent_and_child(parent, child2);

    Research _(relationships);

    return 0;
}
```

That code compiles and works fine.  What I do not get is the line:

```
    Research _(relationships);
```

Why is there an underscore?  Is this a new feature of C++17?  What is it called?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646935/is-single-underscore-a-valid-c-variable-name maybe this one?

Comment: That is just the name of the Research struct instance

Comment: Thank you, all.  That is a very lazy name.  T_T

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it turns out to be a variable name, valid in C++17.  That's a very lazy way of naming things.

Comment: It’s not necessarily lazy—sometimes it means that the name doesn’t matter because the variable exists for the effects of creating/destroying it.  See the duplicate for yet other possible reasons.