# using keyword, what i do wrong?

Tags: c++, using

```
/* ..CODE.. */
struct st_Settings {
    struct {
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;
        unsigned int width;
        unsigned int height;
    } window;
} defaultSettings;
/* ..CODE.. */
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
    using st_Settings; // default settings
    {
        using window;
        {
            x = 50;
            y = 50;
            width = 800;
            height = 600;
        }
    }
    /* ..CODE.. */
}
```

This code doesnt work, and this is my question,
can i replace "using" keyword with something else what working with structures?

---

Okey i have struct like this:

```
struct
{
    struct a
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    }
    struct b
    {
        struct a
        {
            int a;
            int b;
            int c;
        }
        struct b
        {
            int a;
            int b;
            int c;
        }
    }
    struct c
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
    }
} a;
```

Did i must do this:

```
a.a.a = 1;
a.a.b = 12;
a.a.c = 14;

a.b.a.a = 41;
a.b.a.b = 61;
a.b.a.c = 34;

a.b.b.a = 65;
a.b.b.b = 45;
a.b.b.c = 23;

a.c.a = 1;
a.c.b = 0;
a.c.c = 4;
```

Or it is possible to do something like this:

```
a.
{
    a.
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 12;
        c = 14;
    }

    b.
    {
        a.
        {
            a = 41;
            b = 61;
            c = 34;
        }
        b.
        {
            a = 65;
            b = 45;
            c = 23;
        }
    }

    c.
    {
        a = 1;
        b = 0;
        c = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how `using` is used in C++. Get yourself one or more of [these books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The using keyword is applicable for namespace.

Comment: You are mis*using* and ab*using* `using`, quite conf*using*

Comment: @user1929959: actually, I'm not even sure what you're trying to say. Oo

Comment: Using does not do that in c++, it has an entirely different function. There isn't any keyword in c++ that does what you want. You *might* be able to create a variable containing a reference to the sub-object you want to access fields in that to simplify your code, but really, just write the whole thing out, it's clearer, just more typing

Comment: You're looking for a keyword like Pascal's `with`, which [doesn't exist in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2279180/1782465).

Comment: Yes, I searching for something like Pascal's "with" keyword

Answer (score 0):

The `using` keyword is not being used properly in your code (and is not needed at all in this segment of code):

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int iCmdShow) 
{
    st_Settings settings;
    settings.window.x = 50;
    settings.window.y = 50;
    settings.window.width = 800;
    settings.window.height = 600;
    // ...
}
```

Also note that the way you're defining your structure is defining a global instance named `defaultSettings`.  If you wanted to use that instead, you would remove the line declaration of `settings` above, and replace all other instances of it with `defaultSettings`.

Comment: Yes i can but this not looking clearly. What if my struct is larger? I looking for something like namepspace but can be used with structures.

Comment: @user3033514 "something like namespace but can be used with structures" - that makes no sense.  A structure (or class) is a custom data type.  A namespace is just a named grouping for data types.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing near to what you want is initialize the structure when declaring the variable:

```
struct st_Settings {
    struct {
        unsigned int x;
        unsigned int y;
        unsigned int width;
        unsigned int height;
    } window;
} defaultSettings = {{50,50,800,600}};
```

at the same time, you can initialize inside a function:

```
int a = 10 ;
int b = 20 ;
struct st_Settings declaredAndSetted = {{a,b,defaultSettings.window.width,400}} ;
```

If you use c++0x standard (`$ g++ -std=c++0x <file>`) you can reassign values to a structure variable  in this way:

```
defaultSettings = {{a,b,defaultSettings.window.width,400}} ;
```