# Switch into object's namespace locally

Tags: python, pandas, syntax, ipython

Consider the following simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
mytable = pd.read_csv('test.dat',sep='\t')
mytable["z"] = mytable.x + mytable.y
mytable["q"] = mytable.z**2
mytable
```

for example with `cat test.dat`:

```
x       y
1       5
2       6
3       7
4       8
```

If I use something like this for example from `ipython3` I want to "factor out" the `mytable` keyword as in this pseudo code:

```
import pandas as pd
mytable = pd.read_csv('test.dat',sep='\t')
cd mytable
   z = x + y
   q = z**2
mytable
```

Are there any possibilities to simplify syntax like this. It is ok, if the solutions uses additional ipython features.

Remark: I used a "`cd`" keyword following pgf/tikz syntax where something like this is possible.

Comment: Sounds like the `with` keyword from Pascal.  I think there is no such thing in Python possible without massive hacking.  After all Python strives to keep each line expressive without too much context.  Think of the explicitness of `self` in methods which is exactly the opposite of your approach.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279180/does-c-have-with-keyword-like-pascal for the same question in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

Python's design does not really allow for this as it would lead to ambiguities.  See [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesn-t-python-have-a-with-statement-like-some-other-languages.htm) for a detailed discussion on the topic.

Consider a code like this:

```
class X(object):
  def __init__(self, q):
    self.q = q

x = X(4)
q = 3

# del x.q

with x:
  print q
```

This should print 4, I assume.

Now, consider to enable the `del` statement.  Should this then raise an error (because of the missing `q` in `x`?) or should it print 3 (because of the more global variable `q`)?  Since this is hard to decide and different people could validly have different opinions, Python decided not to have this feature at all.